# As a CSS3 flex-box user I would like to consume maximum space on the screen for given divs with a text content

Tags: css, flexbox

Given I have 2 relevant divs with a text content (each) inside a flexbox container
When the content is longer than my screen
Then I should see the width and height of both divs are balanced to consume maximum space

Here is an example where I have 2nd and 3rd div relevant. Both have some text content.
For this example I found manually flex-grow numbers for both divs to do the balance.
**Question: Is it possible to do such balance using only CSS or the certain calculation should be done in JavaScript?**

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    counter-reset: item;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.cell {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #379AD6;
    color: #222;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px white;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #5bbdfa;
}

.cell::before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: 'Grid Item ' counter(item) ' ';
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-container .cell {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flex-container .cell:first-child {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.flex-container .cell:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 34 1;
}

.flex-container .cell:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 16 1;
}

.flex-container .line-break{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid beatae cupiditate doloribus eaque enim et excepturi expedita fuga, minima minus neque nihil non, obcaecati officia quidem quisquam quo repellat repudiandae sapiente sunt ullam ut voluptas. Ab iste nemo numquam, quos ratione recusandae sunt! Cum ex magnam officia quia voluptatum. Reprehenderit?</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores cum cumque dolorem, error ex facere magni minima quaerat voluptas voluptates?</div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell">End</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this with equal spacing http://jsfiddle.net/w3dx/ULQwf/

Comment: @Saravana, with those modern layouts I totally forgot about tables. Your solution works like a charm, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Saravana. However it requires a container to be a table so the other divs will follow the table constraints. For the first div from my example the colspan should do the job but last two wound need to have different display type to not stick with the columns constraint and have their own rules. I will try to play with it a little bit more.